# C++, How do I call a Base classes' overloaded extraction operator in a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, overloading

So this is a small part of a large assignment I have, I'm just unsure of the syntax for this.

I have a base class named `Vehicle`, which has these members: `int fuelAmt` and `int fuelUsage`)

*(I am using namespace `std`)*

I overloaded the `<<` operator this way:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const Vehicle& myVehicle)
{
    cout << "Fuel Usage Rate: " << myVehicle.fuelUsage << endl
         << "Fuel Amount:     " << myVehicle.fuelAmt << endl;

    return osObject;
}
```

I then call it this way:

```
cout << Vehicle;
```

The result is (example):

```
Fuel Usage Rate: 10;
Fuel Amount: 50;
```

---

I also have an `Airplane` class which derives from the `Vehicle` class, it introduces a new member: `int numEngines`.

How can I overload the `<<` operator in the `Airplane` class, so that it will first call the "Vehicle overloaded operator results", and then the results of whatever I tell the `<<` operator to print from the derived class... So, here's what I mean:

I need it to function like this in the `Airplane` class:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const Airplane& myAirplane)
{
        //First print the Fuel Usage rate and Fuel amount by calling
        //the Base class overloaded << function

         //then
        cout << "Number of Engines: " << myAirplane.numEngines << endl;

    return osObject;
}
```

How do I trigger the base class execution of outputting its members' values, in this derived class?

Is it something like changing the header? Like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const Airplane& myAirplane): operator<<Vehicle
```

Comment: In operator<< for Vehicle you write to cout. You should write to osObject.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about the following:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const Airplane& myAirplane)
{
    osObject << static_cast<const Vehicle &>(myAirplane);
    osObject << "Number of Engines: " << myAirplane.numEngines << endl;

    return osObject;
}
```

Comment: you should cast to `const vehicle&`

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: Updated answer with your suggestion

Comment: Shouldn't the `this` in `*static_cast<Vehicle *>(this)` be replaced with `&myAirplane`? Likewise instead of `Airplane.numEngines` shouldn't that be `myAirplane.numEngines`?

Comment: @yasouser: this? What this? It's a nonmember function!

Answer (score 18):

Since the operator << is a nonmember function, you can't declare it virtual, which is ideally what you want. So you do the following

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual std::ostream& output(std::ostream& out) const
    {
        return out << "Base";
    }
    virtual ~Base() {} //Let's not forget to have destructor virtual
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual std::ostream& output(std::ostream& out) const
    {
        Base::output(out); //<------------------------
        return out << "DerivedPart";
    }
    virtual ~Derived() {} //Let's not forget to have destructor virtual
};
```

and finally, have operator << for the base class only and the virtual dispatch will work its magic

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Base& b) 
{
    return b.output(out);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& osObject, const Airplane& myAirplane)
{
     //First print the Fuel Usage rate and Fuel amount by calling
     //the Base class overloaded << function
     cout << (Vehicle& ) myAirplane;

     //then
     cout << "Number of Engines: " << myAirplane.numEngines << endl;

     return osObject;
}
```